# How to build data payload for API in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to build a data payload to send to an API but I am having issues building it dynamically.  This hard coded payload text works:

```
"""
{  
   "Line":[  
      {  
         "Description":"John's Made up Description",
         "Amount":12.00,
         "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
         "SalesItemLineDetail":{  
            "ItemRef":{  
               "value":"15"
            },
            "UnitPrice":"2",
            "Qty":6,
            "TaxCodeRef":{  
               "value":"2"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "CustomerRef":{  
      "value":"9"
   },
   "CustomerMemo":{  
      "value":"This is a test"
   }
}
"""
```

And I've built what I thought was the same with:

```
data = {}
data['Line'] = [{"Description" : "John's made up stuff",
                "Amount" : 12.00,
                "DetailType" : "SalesItemLineDetail",
                "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                    "ItemRef" : {
                        "value" : "15"
                    },
                    "UnitPrice" : "2",
                    "Qty" : 6,
                    "TaxCodeRef" : {
                        "value": "2"
                    }
                }
                }]
data['CustomerRef'] = {"value" : "9"}
data['CustomerMemo'] = {"value" : "hello"}
```

Which returns the following if I do print(data)

```
{  
   'Line':[  
      {  
         'Description':"John's made up stuff",
         'Amount':12.0,
         'DetailType':'SalesItemLineDetail',
         'SalesItemLineDetail':{  
            'ItemRef':{  
               'value':'15'
            },
            'UnitPrice':'2',
            'Qty':6,
            'TaxCodeRef':{  
               'value':'2'
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   'CustomerRef':{  
      'value':'9'
   },
   'CustomerMemo':{  
      'value':'hello'
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if I have looked at this too long and it's something simple or if I am doing this completely wrong.  How can I dynamically create the correct payload?

Comment: You might just be missing to run it through `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 0):

Massive thanks to Kaus here.. can't see the trees from the wood...

```
data = json.dumps(data)
```

Was all it needed to work..